# How can I properly integrate Stack's editor in my website?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to integrate [Stack's editor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor) in my self-written blog. But even at their examples in their README, it isn't displaying the editor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.min.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@latest/highlight.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor-container"></div>
<script>
    new window.stacksEditor.StacksEditor(
        document.querySelector("#editor-container"),
        "*Your* **markdown** here",
        {}
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, the browser's console says, that `stacksEditor`.

Comment: You included the stacks package not the stacks-editor package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adjusted your code. You missed some libraries in your script tags, added them from different CDN's

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/styles.css">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@latest/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="editor-container"></div>
  <script>
    new window.stacksEditor.StacksEditor(
      document.querySelector("#editor-container"),
      "*Your* **markdown** here", {}
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you make it using textarea brother?